# How do I use Aeson to generate a literal (unquoted) javascript expression?

Tags: json, haskell, object-literal, aeson, template-haskell

i'm using [this function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hvega-0.10.0.0/docs/Graphics-Vega-VegaLite.html#v:toHtmlFileWith) and need to pass it an Aeson [`Value`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Value):

```js
{ logLevel : vega.Debug }
```

this is supposed to refer to an [enum](https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/master/packages/vega-util/src/logger.js#L6) in a javascript package that the binding doesn't export.

afaict i'm supposed to use `Data.Aeson.QQ.Simple` for this, but everything i try that compiles puts quotes around `"vega.Debug"`, which i can't have.

```hs
[aesonQQ| { logLevel : "vega.Debug" } |]
```

what am i missing?  is there a way to use [encode](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.4.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:encode) for this?

Comment: `{ logLevel : vega.Debug }` is not a valid JSON, so it can't be written as an Aeson `Value`. Can you clarify what JSON you are really trying to put?

Comment: @Sir4ur0n - oh really? huh! i find javascript so repugnant that i touch it as little as possible, so i barely know anything about it or JSON. i'm trying to set the `logLevel` option as described [here](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed#options). it refers to a type `Level` [here](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view_logLevel), which refers to values like `vega.Debug`, defined in that enum the OP links. if i use a bare Int it works: `toJSON VOpt {logLevel = 2}` where `VOpt` just newtypes an Int and instances `ToJSON`. won't JSON let you put expressions as field values? if not, why?

Comment: If the binding does not expose those constants you could define them manually in your Haskell program, e.g. `Debug :: Int`, `Debug = 1`, and then use `{ logLevel : Debug }`. Would that work for your use case?

Comment: I meant `{ logLevel = Debug }` of course.

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn - that sounds like my `VOpt` hack, i'm trying to figure out how to do it "right" -- ie safe, clean, no repeating :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Aeson `Value`s represent JSON objects only, so they don’t support embedded JavaScript expressions, or any other extensions.

If this API only *accepts* `Value`s, you’re stuck. I think the *best* solution is to just duplicate the integer value of `vega.Debug` and serialise that.

Otherwise, a straightforward solution is to make a modified version of `toHtmlWith` that accepts a more flexible input type, such as a string:

```
toHtmlWith' :: Maybe Text -> VegaLite -> Text
toHtmlWith' mopts vl =
  let spec = encodeToLazyText (fromVL vl)
      -- NB: Removed ‘encodeToLazyText’ call here.
      opts = maybe "" (\o -> "," <> o) mopts

  in TL.unlines
    [ "<!DOCTYPE html>"
    , "<html>"
    , "<head>"
      -- versions are fixed at vega 5, vega-lite 4
    , "  <script src=\"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5\"></script>"
    , "  <script src=\"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@4\"></script>"
    , "  <script src=\"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed\"></script>"
    , "</head>"
    , "<body>"
    , "<div id=\"vis\"></div>"
    , "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
    , "  var spec = " <> spec <> ";"
    , "  vegaEmbed(\'#vis\', spec" <> opts <> ").then(function(result) {"
    , "  // Access the Vega view instance (https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/) as result.view"
    , "  }).catch(console.error);"
    , "</script>"
    , "</body>"
    , "</html>"
    ]
```

Then you can call `encodeToLazyText` on your own Aeson values, or include arbitrary `Text` strings as needed.

If you *really* want to avoid duplicating the page contents, then you could also call the existing `toHtmlWith` with a `Value` containing a special delimiter that you control, such as `String "<user1441998>vega.Debug</user1441998>"`, and then use that delimiter to postprocess the result:

```
unquoteHackSplices = replace "\"<user1441998>" ""
  . replace "</user1441998>\"" ""
```

> is there a way to use encode for this?

As yet another hack, you could make a `ToJSON` instance for your type that implements `toEncoding` but *not* `toJSON`, and have the encoded value be a JavaScript expression (i.e. invalid JSON). You would want to make `toJSON` raise an error so you don’t use it inadvertently.

---

If you want to generate JavaScript code in general, I would have a look at [`language-javascript`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-javascript). Instead of producing a `Value`, produce a [`JSExpression`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-javascript-0.7.1.0/docs/Language-JavaScript-Parser-AST.html#t:JSExpression) and then use one of the pretty-printing functions like [`renderToText`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-javascript-0.7.1.0/docs/Language-JavaScript-Pretty-Printer.html#v:renderToText) to render it. Here’s a sketch of the structure of a possible solution:

```
-- Like ‘ToJSON’ but may produce arbitrary JavaScript expressions
class ToJavaScript a where
  toJavaScript :: a -> JSExpression

-- Helper function to convert from Aeson Value
jsFromJson :: Value -> JSExpression
jsFromJson v = case v of
  Object o -> JSObjectLiteral …
  Array a -> JSArrayLiteral …
  String s -> JSStringLiteral …
  …

instance ToJavaScript YourType where
  toJavaScript = …

rendered :: Text
rendered = renderToText
  $ JSAstExpression (toJavaScript yourValue) JSNoAnnot
```

Your expression would have the form:

```
JSMemberDot
  (JSIdentifier JSNoAnnot "vega")
  JSNoAnnot
  (JSIdentifier JSNoAnnot "Debug")
```

The `JSAnnot` type would also allow you to include comments in the generated result. Bear in mind that the `language-javascript` pretty-printing is likely less well optimised than Aeson’s JSON serialisation.

Comment: thanks for the super thorough answer!  the `toEncoding` idea seems small and clean, any reason you downplay it?  :)

Comment: @user1441998: I don’t know if it’ll work, mainly, since I don’t know if there are cases that go through `toJSON` first when they should go through `toEncoding`. Also it does break what I would *expect* to be invariants of `ToJSON`, namely that going through `toEncoding` and `encode . toJSON` should produce the same end result.